# Ternary Tree Path List Matlab

Tags: matlab, tree

I have created a ternary tree in matlab as below.

```
for i=1:4
    a(i, j:j+2) = 1;
    a(j:j+2, i) = 1;
    j=j+3;
end
```

This code works fine and the numbering of the tree is in pre-order starting with Root Node as 1 and then the nodes are numbered as

```
               1
---------------------------------------------------
2                                 3                         4
---------------------------------------------------------
5 6 7                          8 9 10                   11 12 13
```

My question is how to write code that will get the paths
1 2 5, 1 2 6, 1 2 7 and similarly for the rest and save these paths to a file. I am doing some trial and error codes now.

Comment: @mehmet, thanks for the formatting. I am new to all this.

Comment: I have written code to convert the above adjacency matrix to an adjacency list.